# SQL Server : trigger to update another table after insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two SQL Server tables,

- the first one is populated by a web service
- and the second one is used by a software that our company uses for the customer registries.

Right now I have a stored procedure, scheduled in a SQL Server Agent job, which takes all new entries from the table 1, prepares them and inserts them into a table 2.

This job runs once a day and works fine. But I need to do this more often. The web service is not used so often  but I need to do an insert in table 2 every time a person uses the web service.

First, I planned to schedule the existing job every 2 minutes, just to check if there are any new rows. But I am not sure if that’s OK for performance of the server?

Then I thought about SQL Server triggers which I haven't use before. I wrote an "after insert" trigger to start the existing SQL Server job but, then the web service stopped working. The web service checks the unique e-mail address.

If I understood triggers right, the trigger will generate a new "inserted table", so every time a user wants to register in the web service and the trigger is active, the user gets the error message "the e-mail address is already in use".

I can’t change the structure of tables or the logic of the web service. I have to adapt the data from table 1 to fit into table 2 so I can’t use replication either.

I would appreciate if you could give me some ideas, how to solve the problem with the trigger or if there's another solution I could use?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `INSERTED` table is a "hidden" internal table only. It will contain the latest inserted rows, but should not interfere with the original table. When you say the web service stops working, what do you mean, exactly? Is it throwing errors? Can you see the new row in the second table at all? Does the trigger work as expected?

Comment: When the trigger is running, the `Inserted` pseudo table contains the **newly inserted rows** that caused this trigger to fire. This is only temporary, only for the duration of the trigger run - that will not cause your web service to stop ....

Comment: This is the flow: the user uses the web service for registration and this will insert a row in  table 1. If I put an "After insert" trigger on that table and user tries to register than the user gets the following error "e-mail address is already in use", so no registration is made. When you try with the same e-mail address without the trigger - the registration goes fine and a new row is inserted in table 1. The email-address is used as UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on table 1. That's only when the trigger is enabled that it's saying that the e-mail address is already in use (although it's not).

Comment: @user1653278 - That does not make sense. A trigger on table 1 would not cause a duplicate `INSERT` unless the trigger logic does that. Can you show us the code for the trigger? 

Keep in mind that the flow is the following:

1. Record is inserted in table1.
2. Trigger fires.
3. Trigger reads from `INSERTED` to find the value inserted.
4. Whatever the trigger does

I realy do not see how this would cause a duplicate INSERT unless it's coded as such. Are you sure the TRIGGER inserts into table 2 and not accidentally table1?

Comment: You  might want to look at [change data capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx). Instead of delaying the web service while you process the data in a trigger you can handle the new data separately.

Comment: You didn't say anythong regarding the table structures, the unique constraints.  Perhaps the fix that is required is just to change the code in the trigger to perform a Merge command rather than insert, and on 'When Matched' increment a counter.  Or maybe the unique constraint needs to be changed.  The issue may not be in the trigger itself.  So more information about the schema and behavior would be helpful.